# How do I create text SearchView for WebView in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I'm almost done with my first Android App project and all I've been desperately looking for is a way to let the users of my app search text. My app simply has WebView on different Activities and Fragments. Simple HTML pages I designed using HTML and CSS specifically for this app and are fetched from the server. They provide a long list of items to choose from.  All I want create is a 'Find on Page' tool found in almost all browsers to simply highlight text that is being put in the search bar.

All I have is this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf4hx.png)

I want to create something like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8h7G.png)

Hope someone can be of help. I'm really desperate. It's my last piece.